# No compatible targets were found

Tags: android, eclipse, project-properties

I am having

target android-4

in project.properties. In eclipse when I run the project I am getting the error

> No compatible targets were found

How to resolve this>

Comment: You run your application in which device or Emulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Create AVD that supports android-4(Android 1.6)** or change your `android-4 target to android-8.`

**How to create new AVD ?**

```
on Eclipse, [Window> Android AVD Manager] select,

you press the [new] button, you can create new Android Virtual Device
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to create an emulator or use a device that is compatible with this target. i.e the device or emulator should have a android version that is compatible with this project.

For running an Emulator instance, you will have to create a virtual android device. For this you will need the AVD - In Eclipse click "Window -> Android SDK and AVD manager" Click create new AVD and this screen will pop up. Create the virtual device with your target or higher and run your project.

[image]

check this tutorial out for more info:
https://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html

Answer (score 1):

try to change the `target android-4` to `target android-15` in your project.properties and than refresh the project run again

Answer (score 1):

you can either run an app on the emulator or an actual device.

to run it on the emulator you need to create a matching virtual device first ( see http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/index.html )

to run it on the device, plug in a device and install the proper usb driver (see http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to run the application on your phone; I had the same problem and I found a solution that worked for me:

Try enabling **USB Debugging** on your phone.

I have a Samsung Galaxy SIII and I enabled USB Debugging by going into **Settings > Developer Options**. Then check the **USB Debugging** option and allow your computer to install the necessary drivers when connected. Hope this helps!

Comment: @downvoter Add a comment if you take issue with the answer. This worked for me and also helped someone else, so downvoting without comment isn't doing anyone a favor.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing on Windows, to debug on a device, first you have to install the driver using these instructions here:

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

You can find the driver in the ...\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\ folder.

Then you will have to enable USB debugging on your device.

On most devices running Android 3.2 or older, you can find the option under Settings > Applications > Development.

On Android 4.0 and newer, it's in Settings > Developer options.

On Android 4.2 and newer, Developer options is hidden by default. To make it available, go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options.

Answer (score -1):

***Galaxy S4*** users need to go to **Settings > More button > About device**

Next you have to tap Build number (greyed out) **7 times** then you get an option in previous menu called **Developer options**, select this and then tick **USB debugging**